# Why key_points is None with some images while using sift.detectAndCompute(image, None)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, sift

I want to get similarities between the two images. I used OpenCV sift method. I tried with many OpenCV versions on python 3.7:

- opencv 4.5.2 (conda)
- opencv 4.5.1 (conda)
- opencv 3.4.2 (conda)
- opencv 4.5.3.56 (pip opencv-python)

I used code like this:

```
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(descriptor1, descriptor2, k=2)
```

When I used the method, I got this error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) ../modules/features2d/src/matchers.cpp:761: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _queryDescriptors.type() == trainDescType in function 'knnMatchImpl'
```

When I searched about the error, The reason for the error was that key_points were None. The error came from

```
key_points, descriptor = sift.detectAndCompute(image, None)
```

While the sift.detectAndCompute method give correct results in some images, it did not work in some images. Like this image didn't work :

[image]

But this image worked:

[image]

I run the script like this:

```
import cv2

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

reference_keypoint, reference_descriptor = sift.detectAndCompute("reference_image.png", None)
target_keypoint, target_descriptor = sift.detectAndCompute("target_image.png", None)
matches = bf.knnMatch(reference_descriptor, target_descriptor, k=2)
...
```

Why am I getting the result of "descriptor" None on some images?

Comment: Because SIFT didnt find any keypoints... Sift basically uses a blob-detector for detection. I guess the possible "blobs" in your images are too big. Maybe you could detect a keypoint un your first image if you scale it down or if you increase the number of octaves.

Comment: I tried resizing the image for this method but it didn't work. How can I increase the number of octaves?

Comment: I think in SIFT_create() there might be the possibility to ass parameters

Comment: I did it but didn't work. Thanks for your response

Comment: ok sorry, then probably the image content isnt suitable for detecting "blobs" according to the sift algorithm. Typically, sift is used for textured regions and I was even surprised that keypoints are detected in the second image.